# Have 2 different applications use 2 different ip's with the same port on the same host

Tags: networking, debian, ip, alias, ovh

I want to have an application running on `x.x.x.x:80` and another one at `y.y.y.y:80` on the same host. I have bought 2 ips from ovh and would like to know how to do so.

I found these:
[Debian/OVH: How to configure multiple Failover IP on the same Xen (Debian) Virtual Machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/422085/debian-ovh-how-to-configure-multiple-failover-ip-on-the-same-xen-debian-virtu)

But it just makes ip y.y.y.y be the same as x.x.x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I did setup the ip addresses correctly. But this might be REALLY helpful for others and save a LOT of time. The problem I was having that apache didn't have an ip specified, so all of the ips I setup would lead to apache page. I solved it by adding an ip to apache ports.conf file

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with interface aliasing. eth0 will have one IP and eth0:0 will have the other. See [this entry in the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration#Multiple_IP_addresses_on_one_Interface)

Comment: I wish I could have 2 right answers as this did help me too

Answer (score -1):

This is impossible as the IP address is attached to a NIC card, and each NIC card can only use one IP at once. To have two applications using two IP addresses on one host, you would need two NIC cards (two ports) (this is as far as I know. I may be wrong)

Comment: A NIC has a MAC address, not an IP address. You are off by a  network layer.

Comment: The principle is still the same.

Comment: Not at all, it isn't. A NIC can have many layer-3 protocols and addresses, but only one MAC address. In fact IPv6 not only allows multiple IP addresses on one NIC, but requires it.

Comment: And that is why I stated that I may be wrong

Comment: And that is why I made my comment. You are incorrect. BTW, I'm not the one who voted down. I was merely trying to point out that you were incorrect.